Is this too much like self help
Has anyone looked into whether doing nothing at all -- so just sitting or lying down until you can work -- raises motivation in those affected by a clinically significant lack of motivation
Is that too much like self help to ask?

Until framed into a more general scientifically themed question, I would find this unsuitable for any scientific stack

so i add the word study or clinical experience, and it's fine?

Ideally, you should embed your question in a scientific framework based on valid data from peer-reviewed journals. At the least, add some web-links to show the exact problem you describe (lack of motivation) and the solution you describe (procrastination) are related to each other in any obvious way. In a nut shell -- add your prior research efforts.

just out of curiosity, you have a well amount of reputation. Why do you not knowing how the site works?

i don't know...

The question may or may not be seen as a self help question but either way there is ironically, a distinct lack of motivation in the question.
A question with the required level of motivation will have been researched by reading books on the subject or web searching prior to asking.
As you may know seeing as you have a fair amount of reputation on this site, for this reason among others, we work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should show evidence of prior research.
If there were references to books and/or websites on the subject along with anything you don't understand etc. the question could stand on its merits as a question arising out of interest in gaining more knowledge on the subject.
